# Erro ao gerar build para ios - app em Ionic

Tags: ionic

Estou rodando o seguinte comando para gerar o build:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod
```

ou

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

Versão do typescript instalada: 2.6.2

esse é o erro ao rodar o comando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo abrir o projeto no Xcode e executar no emulador normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recentemente tive esse problema, execute os passos a seguir e tente novamente

1 - Remova @IonicPage () dos arquivos `.ts`

2 - Exclua `.module.ts`

Comment: Fiz esse processo, e tentei rodar o comando novamente, e deu o seguinte erro: Cannot find type definition file for '@types'. você sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: tente npm install ou instala o ionic do projeto novamente e rode para ver o que aparece

Comment: Ou para ser mais direto caso o comentário de cima nao ajude, tente npm install --save @types/npm

Comment: Deu certo amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!